# SSAS 2008, Translate Hierarchy members in parent-child hierarchy

Tags: translation, ssas, olap

I'm creating my dimensions and parent-child hierarchies using AMO objects. One of the requirements is to translate the hierarchy members into another language.

While accessing the newly created cube in the BIDS, I am able to provide translation for the attributes in Dimension Editor, but I'm not sure how do I do the same for the  hierarchy. 
My DimCompany table has a few fields, including CompanyKey, CompanyParent, CompanyName, CompanyRusName. The last one is to be used to translate attributes and hierarchy members.

I have provided a couple of screenshots explaining the existing situation.

Unfortunately, I can't post images, so just a couple of links here:

- "English language - all fine" http://db.tt/PjshtUKt
- "Russian language - problems with hierarchy members"
  http://db.tt/4Rf3yM2j

I'd very grateful for any hints and suggestions!

Regards,
Galiya

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the images.  Both links aren't working.

Since your table has both CompanyName and CompanyRusName, you translate your dimension like this:

- Open the Dimension Editor
- Click on the Translations Tab
- Right click on the view and choose New Translation (or Menu Dimension > New Translation
- Choose the Language
- The new Language will appear as a column.

Now,

- Next, for the Attribute you want to translate (in your case, CompanyName would be an attribute, if you don't see the attribute, you have to make it an attribute first), click in the cell and a button with a "." will appear, click on the button and
- The Attribute Data Translation dialog will appear
- In this dialog box, you can choose the Translation Caption and the Translation Column
- In the Translation Column, choose the (in your example) CompanyRusName.

Let me know if this help.

Comment: Hi Patrice, thank you for your time. Strange you can't see the images (I've just double checked them in google chrome's incognito window - seems ok). Yes, the steps you've described has been done before. The problem I can see that my hierarchy members are not translated, while Attributes are!

Comment: Next to the Translations, there's a Browser tab.  Can you see the translation when you select the Language?

Comment: Patrice, I've added a few screenshots in dropbox, coupld you please take a look? Answering you question - yes, for attributes, but not for hierarchy members. [screenshot1](http://db.tt/PjshtUKt), [screenshot2](http://db.tt/4Rf3yM2j), [screenshot3](http://db.tt/nlhgjSOV), [screenshot4](http://db.tt/F1z3Qxwh), [screenshot5](http://db.tt/w5D7LO48). Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: I just tried the same thing (translating a Hierarchy) and it worked on my side.  From the screenshots, I do notice that my hierarchy seems different than yours.  In the Dimension Translation Tab, I can expand the hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to be possible on your side (looking at Screenshot3).  Can you review the hierarchy ?

Comment: Patrice, is your hierarchy is a parent-child one? And I'm sorry, but  I'm not sure I understood what you mean by "In the Dimension Translation Tab, I can expand the hierarchy". Any chance for a screenshot-example? Thanks a million!

Comment: Here are the screenshots of my dimension: [https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!450&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!ABSkWz5Y8qiwTSs](screenshot01), [https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!451&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!AA7TtDvStW6cKP0](screenshot2), [https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!452&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!ALRDjeI8QGkK76I](screenshot3)

Comment: and [screenshot4](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!453&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!AJ864NxLXo8NGuE)

Comment: Patrice, I don't have access to the first three pics, only screenshot4 can be open. What could be the difference? Thank you.

Comment: Second try:  [Screenshot1](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!450&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!ABSkWz5Y8qiwTSs), [Screenshot2](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!451&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!AA7TtDvStW6cKP0), [Screenshot3](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1ebd90d91afd9cd4&resid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!452&parid=1EBD90D91AFD9CD4!332&authkey=!ALRDjeI8QGkK76I).

Comment: Hi Patrice, thanks a lot for your help and for screenshots. After checking those I realised that we are talking about different hierarchies here. Yours is a typical cube hierarchy, while mine was built as a parent-child one, and that was the reason that it couldn't be expanded it. Thanks again, it gave me a few ideas of the changes I need to do it my design.